How do I apply for a US visitor visa after overstaying less than 180 days?
I travelled to the USA in 2008 alone on the Visa Waiver Program from the UK. Whilst there, I met someone who I thought was the one. He is a USA citizen. We got married and I was going to apply for the spouse visa. His mom sent his birth certificate, which we needed, but it had a different name than the person I had married. He had changed his name, but not through any legal channels.
This meant I could not apply for the spouse visa as there was nothing linking the 2 names. At this point I had overstayed around 165 days, so I booked flights home to England so I didn't overstay more than 180 days. I was 12 weeks pregnant when I came home.
I went to the US embassy in London around 2 months after I came back for an interview for a visit visa, which was declined as I didn't have enough strong enough ties to the UK.
The relationship broke down within a year, but we have never divorced. We rarely have contact.
I now have 3 children and I want to take them to Disney World, Florida for a 2-week holiday. Do I just apply for a B2 visa? Will my children use the Visa Waiver Program? I read I had to take the documents from my previous visit to the US Embassy but I no longer have them. Will it be seen as a problem that my 'husband' lives in the USA? I have no plans on meeting up with him as he hasn't shown any interest in our son in all these years. It is 15 years since I left the USA.
I have a rented house which I have been in for 14 years, a job in banking I have been in for 15 months, a car, my 3 children in school, and I am a carer for my Mam. I also have 2 dogs. I am financially stable and secure.

Maybe someone will have something useful to say, but this strikes me as the sort of situation for which you may want to seek the advice of a lawyer.

I’d take the children to Disneyland Paris, TBH. A lot easier without the stress of US immigration

@SaranshSharma In the question, the OP wrote "...At this point I had overstayed around 165 days..." Seems very clear to me that they admitted they overstayed.

Can you confirm that one of your three children  was fathered by your US husband? Do they have American citizenship?

Did you overstay by 165 days (180+165=345 days in total) or just stayed there for 165 days (so you still were inside the limits of the VWP)?  The writing is a bit awkward.
In any case, the marriage should probably be sorted out first.

@Chieron: VWP status is only for 90 days.

Side comment: in most cases one doesn’t need a legal change, an affidavit from someone that has know one before and after and that the change wasn’t done in order to perpetuate a fraud would be sufficient.  That would get you a passport.  The “Mom” that sent the birth certificate should have been able to do that.

@user102008 ah, right. Quite a long stay without making sure about the legality in any case..

@jmoreno: I-130 instructions, page 8, says that if the name on the document is different, you need to provide a legal document reflecting the name change, such as a marriage certificate, adoption decree, or court order.

@user102008: page 9, requirement 8, section D.  Two affidavits.

@jmoreno: That's if the document proving relationship (e.g. birth certificate for a petition between a parent and a child, or marriage certificate for a spouse petition) is not available. But here, the document (marriage certificate) is available; it just has the wrong legal name on it.

@user102008: no, the event “name change” is what is being proved. Speaking from experience here, although I did have to provide the law from two states to prove it was legal and not a crime to change your name without a court order or marriage certificate. Although that does depend on state (hence showing it was legal in both the state I was in and the state where the change took place).

Surely the son is a US citizen because his father is. Or is he a scam artistt?

Yes my eldest Sons Father is a US citizen but I've never looked into getting my Son Citizenship. I have just checked his Birth Certificate and I have put my 'Husbands' new name (who I married), but i also added,  Also Known As, and I put his Birth name.

Would they really think I am intending on going back to him after 15 years apart? I have 2 more children now

@lambshaanxy Yes my eldest Sons Father is a US citizen but I've never looked into getting my Son Citizenship. I have just checked his Birth Certificate and I have put my 'Husbands' new name (who I married), but i also added, Also Known As, and I put his Birth name.

@Natalie No point in "getting him" citizenship. He already has.

My son was born in the UK and has a British passport

Since you have previously had a visa denied, and this is a visit for tourism, your only option is to apply for a B2 visa.  Assuming they're UK citizens, your children can travel on the VWP though.
I would strongly recommend legally divorcing your former US partner first though, otherwise it will look like you are moving to be with him.
I would second @Traveller's recommendation to go to Disneyland Paris instead though, it would be far easier.

"Since you have previously had a visa denied, and this is a visit for tourism, your only option is to apply for a B2 visa." There is no rule that having a visa denied means they can never use the VWP again. On the other hand, the fact that they overstayed VWP means that they can never use VWP again.

@user102008 To use VWP, OP would have to apply for ESTA, and one of the ESTA questions is whether they have ever been denied a visa previously.  Answering "yes" to that, as OP would have to do, virtually guarantees that the ESTA will also be denied.

There's no official rule saying that answering Yes to that question definitely leads to ESTA denial. All we have are people's anecdotal reports of denials.

@user102008 Official rule or not, given the history here I would be astonished if the OP applies for ESTA and is approved.  But hey, if she wants to spend $21 for a lottery ticket, go ahead!

Well, the OP will definitely not be approved for ESTA, because there is an official law (8 USC 1187(a)(7)) that says the OP cannot be allowed to use VWP, but it's not because of a visa denial; it's because of overstaying VWP.
